# Are Squarespace RSS feeds blocked by PHP file pull requests?

Tags: php, rss, squarespace

Squarespace has a built-in RSS feed for all blogs, etc. that use its service, and you can view the RSS feed for any blog by appending ?format=rss to the end of the URL for the blog. For example, http://denverdarling.com/home is a blog through Squarespace, and you can view the RSS feed for that blog through http://denverdarling.com/home?format=rss

When you manually type in the URL for the RSS feed within a browser's address bar it shows the RSS contents without any trouble. However, when I try to pull the same contents with a PHP script, I get an error every time that says "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"

I have tried a few different PHP functions to pull the content, but they all result in the same error. I have also tried this with several different Squarespace blogs, and again they all result in the same error. The PHP functions that I have tried include: `file_get_contents`, `fopen`, `simplexml_load_file`, `DOMDocument()->load()`, etc. Which all result in a "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error.

The only thing that I see when I google the topic is that you can't pull the RSS feed for a password protected blog, but since none of the blogs I've tried to pull the feeds for are password protected, I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that they are blocking headless user agents

```
<?php

$url = "http://denverdarling.com/home?format=rss";

$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

this works, they or their host is checking the header in the request and filtering out particular things

Comment: Hi @Ryan, I had the same issue with `amazon.com` using `file_get_contents` and with adding headers to impersonate as browser request, it worked for couple of days. But, since two days, amazon treating this as headerless requests and unable to fetch information. I am using `"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36\r\n")`. Any advice?

Comment: Hi @theKing, sorry for the delay, only think I could think of would be opening the dev tools on a browser and look at what is happening if you try to reproduce the issue on a browser, they may be using redirects to block these kinds of requests.  If you need a more robust tool, I highly recommend pulling Guzzle into your project https://docs.guzzlephp.org